# Service in front of Hadoop

Tags: web-services, hadoop, architecture, oozie

I would like to expose a web service in front of Hadoop, that is used to forward data to Hadoop ecosystem. I have two branches in Hadoop, slower, that works on whole data periodically, and fast, that does some computation on every input, and stores the data for periodical job. But the user does not see the slower branch, and has a feeling that only the fast job is done, not knowing for the slower job that runs on data aggregated during time.

How to organize my architecture best? I am new to Hadoop architecture, I read about Oozie, and have a feeling that it can help me to some point. But I don't know how to connect the service with Hadoop, how to pass the data through service, since Hadoop works primarily on files, and is distributed system.

Data should get into system in a streaming fashion. There should be "real time" branch, that works with individual values that get into system, and they would also be accumulated for periodic batch processing.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [hue](http://gethue.com/) . This provides a set of web front-ends: there's one for HDFS (the filesystem) where you can upload files; there are means to track jobs too.

If you aim more regular and automated putting of files into HDFS, please elaborate your question further: where and what is the data initially (logs? db? bunch of gzipped csv-s?), what should trigger retrieval/

One can as well use API-s to deal with the filesystem and to track jobs.

As for what oozie concerns, this is more of an orchestrating tool, use it to organize related jobs into workflows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited the question by describing how should data get into system.